# Protocol in Latex

Tags: beamer, templates, algorithms

I want to create a protocol like the following picture. I also mention I work in beamer.

[image]
My attempt is

```
\[
\begin{array}{c c c}
\text{\textsf{\underline{\textbf{Prover}}}} & & \text{\textsf{\underline{\textbf{Verifier}}}} \\
k_{\text{sk}},\,k_{r},\,k_{b} \xleftarrow{\$} \mathbb{Z}_q & & \\
A_y = g^{k_\text{sk}} & & \\
A_D = D^{k_\text{r}} & & \\
A_{\Bar{y}} = (\frac{y}{\Bar{y}})^{k_r} & \xrightarrow{\hspace{1em}A_y,\,A_D,\,A_{\Bar{y}}\hspace{1em}} & \\
& & c\xleftarrow{\$} \mathbb{Z}_q \\
& \xleftarrow{\hspace{2.7em}c\hspace{2.7em}} & \\

\end{array}
\]
```

[image]

I want the letters to start from a straight line.

Comment: And, what's the problem?

Comment: @Ignasi I want the letters to start from a straight line.

Comment: @mathali Can you update your question so it actually says what the problem is? The title, as it is now, is rather non-descriptive and unlikely to help future users with the same problem to find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also want to align the three `=` symbols vertically, right?. If that's the case, using two additional, nested `array` environments for the material in the "Prover" column will let you accomplish your formatting goal.

I would also like to suggest that you simplify and streamline your code. E.g., I believe that `\text{\textsf{\underline{\textbf{Prover}}}}` may be written more succinctly as `\underline{\textbf{Prover}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} ccc @{}}
\underline{\textbf{Prover}} & & \underline{\textbf{Verifier}} \\[1ex]
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}[b]{l}
k_{\mathsf{sk}},\, k_{r},\, k_{b} \xleftarrow{\$} \mathbb{Z}_q \\
  \begin{array}[b]{ll}
    A_y   & {}= g^{k_\mathsf{sk}}  \\
    A_D   & {}= D^{k_\mathsf{r}} \\
    A_{\Bar{y}} & {}= (y/\Bar{y})^{k_r} 
  \end{array}
\end{array}
& \xrightarrow{\hspace{1em} A_y,\, A_D,\, A_{\Bar{y}} \hspace{1em}} \\
& & c\xleftarrow{\$} \mathbb{Z}_q \\
& \xleftarrow{\hspace{2.7em}c\hspace{2.7em}} 
\end{array}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` and some simplifications of your code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{fleqn}
    \[
    \begin{array}{@{}l c c}
    \textsf{\underline{\textbf{Prover}}} & & \textsf{\underline{\textbf{Verifier}}} \\
    k_{\text{sk}},\,k_{r},\,k_{b} \xleftarrow{\$} \mathbb{Z}_q & & \\
    A_y = g^{k_\text{sk}} & & \\
    A_D = D^{k_\text{r}} & & \\
    A_{\Bar{y}} = (\frac{y}{\Bar{y}})^{k_r} & \xrightarrow{\hspace{1em}A_y,\,A_D,\,A_{\Bar{y}}\hspace{1em}} & \\
    & & c\xleftarrow{\$} \mathbb{Z}_q \\
    & \xleftarrow{\hspace{2.7em}c\hspace{2.7em}} & \\
    \end{array}
    \]
    \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh: yes ! I should have changed the specifier of the  first column in the array! Thanks, Mico, I'lll fix that instantly.